# What does Node head; means in this code;

Tags: java

```
class LinkedList
{
    Node head;  // head of list

    /* Linked list Node*/
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;

        // Constructor to create a new node
        // Next is by default initialized as null
        Node(int d) {data = d;}
    }
}
```

Comment: As in the comment said it is the head of list.

Answer (score 2):

Singly-linked list consists of *nodes* connected to each other using the `next` link. The initial node in the chain is commonly referred to as the *"head of the list"*.

`Node head` field in your code holds a reference to the initial element of the linked list:

[image: Linked list]

Answer (score 0):

It declares a variable of type `Node` with identifier `head` with the class as the scope (i.e. the variable can be accessed anywhere in the class).

The variable is uninitialized and is therefore `null` until it is given a value.

Comment: So Node is a variable type in java?

Comment: Yes, you could say that. `Node` is a class, and in Java most variables are either a primitive type (`int`, `boolean`, etc) or an instance of a class (e.g. `String`, `JFrame`, `Node`).

Comment: So Node is a class in java and we redefine it in the example, are we overriding the Node class?

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic linked list. The Node head is literally the first item on the list. The `Node head` just references the 'head' node. Let's say you have a LinkedList of 2 items, then you would want to access the second item as follows (assuming your `Node head` is public, and your `Node next` is public in your Node class)

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
Node secondItem = list.head.next;
```